# Does libevent allow to run callback for timer/io in a different thread?

Tags: c++, c, libevent

Due to some application reasons I need to run callback for timer/io events in a different thread.

Example:

```
void EventLoop::createIOEvent(int fd, short kind, event_cb originalCallback, void* originalUserData) 
{
    ...
    const auto data{std::make_shared<UserData>(originalUserData, originalCallback, callbackExecutor)};
    event* event{event_new(_eventBase, fd, kind, EventLoop::asyncCall, data.get())};
    event_add(event, nullptr);
    ...
}

void EventLoop::asyncCall(int fd, short kind, void* data)
{
    const auto userData{*(reinterpret_cast<UserData*>(data))};
    ExecutorWrapper(userData._callbackExecutor)
        .addRunnable([=]() {
            userData._originalCallback(fd, kind, userData._originalUserData);
    })
    .exec();
 }
```

Is it legal for libevent to use such approach?

Note: it seems that all works fine on Macos and iOS but on Android my test application just closes without any reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it legal for libevent to use such approach?

So access to event/event_base can be done from multiple threads, in this case you need to enable threading support for libevent:

```c
evthread_use_pthreads(); // or similar
```

And later use `BEV_OPT_THREADSAFE` for `bufferevent` thread-safety.

For more details take a look [in the book](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/Ref1_libsetup.html#_locks_and_threading).

And even though your approach should work after this modifications, it is not a good design choice. It will be way more better to create event workers (separate `event_base` + thread) and schedule your event (`event_add`) in the `event_base` of the background thread.

> Android my test application just closes without any reasons.

Need details.